# DotNetOpenId - Open Id get some data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth

I'm using OpenId on a new website and am trying to get some basic information about the user, see the code below. Why is the following allways null?

```
var myData = response.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>();
```

And the main code

```
[System.Web.Mvc.AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
        IAuthenticationResponse response = openid.GetResponse();

        if (response != null)
        {
            switch (response.Status)
            {
                case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(
                        response.ClaimedIdentifier, false);
                    var myData = response.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>();
                    break;
                case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("loginIdentifier",
                        "Login was cancelled at the provider");
                    break;
                case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("loginIdentifier", 
                        "Login failed using the provided OpenID identifier");
                    break;
            }
        }



        return View("Register");
    }

    [System.Web.Mvc.AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult LogOn(string loginIdentifier)
    {
        if (!Identifier.IsValid(loginIdentifier))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("loginIdentifier",
                        "The specified login identifier is invalid");
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
            IAuthenticationRequest request = openid.CreateRequest(
                Identifier.Parse(loginIdentifier));

            // Require some additional data
            request.AddExtension(new ClaimsRequest
            {
                Email = DemandLevel.Request,
                FullName = DemandLevel.Request
            });

            return request.RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
        }
    }
```

Comment: For anyone who is having this issue, check out this - http://dotnetopenauth.net:8000/wiki/CodeSnippets/OpenIDRP/AXFetchAsSregTransform 

I can now get an email from Google but still nothign from Yahoo (I dont think they support AX)

Comment: Liam, Yahoo won't give you any user attributes unless you're on their special whitelist of RPs, which only a handful of RPs are.  So if you're getting an email from Google, I'd say you have it right.

Comment: Ive managed to crack it now, thanks for this. It was the wiki article I posted below which helped me out! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/help/the-axfetchassregtransform-behavior/