# OpenAuth .Net Claims Request is always null

Tags: .net, openid, dotnetopenauth

I've been using DoNetOpenAuth library and followed the example [here](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/programmatic-openid-relying-party/)

The authentication is working, but even though I require an email, the claimsresponse is null.
In fact, it doesn't matter what I require, claimsresponse is always null. Not sure what I'm doing wrong and I'd appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my login button code

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        //Login button has been pushed. Add an extension and redirect
        using (OpenIdRelyingParty openId = new OpenIdRelyingParty())
        {
            IAuthenticationRequest request = openId.CreateRequest( txtOpenID.Text );

            request.AddExtension( new ClaimsRequest
                                    {
                                        Email = DemandLevel.Require,
                                        Country = DemandLevel.Request,
                                        TimeZone = DemandLevel.Request
                                    } );

            request.RedirectToProvider();

        }
    }
```

Here is the page load code. ClaimsResponse variable is always null though.

```
protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        OpenIdRelyingParty openId = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
        var response = openId.GetResponse();

        //check if we're processing a request
        if(response != null)
        {
            switch ( response.Status )
            {
                case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:

                    //authentication worked. grab our required fields
                    var claimsResponse = response.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>();

                    //TODO enter required fields into the database

                    break;
                case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
                    //TODO handle cancel
                    break;

                case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:
                    //TODO handle failed
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your link appears to be dead, at least from where I am. Can you post your code here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DotNetOpenId - Open Id get some data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593506/dotnetopenid-open-id-get-some-data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At last:
The issue is in the web.config

add

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true"/>
</configSections>
</configuration>

<dotNetOpenAuth>
<openid>
<relyingParty>
<behaviors>
<add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth"/>
                </behaviors>
</relyingParty>
</openid>
</dotNetOpenAuth>
```

That is alll and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I face the same problem with both Yahoo & google.
however this MVC sample works great in this sample [working Sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/OpenIdFormsAuth.aspx).... I faced this problem when I tried to convert this solution to ordinary ASP.NET 2

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (this.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
    {
        var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
        string openid_identifier = this.openid_identifier.Text;
        IAuthenticationRequest request = Openid.CreateRequest(Identifier.Parse(openid_identifier));
        var fields = new ClaimsRequest();
        fields.Email = DemandLevel.Require;
        fields.FullName = DemandLevel.Require;               
        request.AddExtension(fields);
        this.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        request.RedirectingResponse.Send();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
        IAuthenticationResponse response = openid.GetResponse();
        if (Request.Params["ReturnUrl"] != null)
            Session["ReturnUrl"] = Request.Params["ReturnUrl"];
        if (response != null && response.Status == AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated)
        {
            var claimUntrusted = response.GetUntrustedExtension<ClaimsResponse>();
            var claim = response.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>();
            UserData userData = null;
            if (claim != null)
            {
                userData = new UserData();
                userData.Email = claim.Email;
                userData.FullName = claim.FullName;
            }
            //now store Forms Authorisation cookie 
            IssueAuthTicket(userData, true);
            //store ClaimedIdentifier it in Session 
            //(this would more than likely be something you would store in a database I guess
            Session["ClaimedIdentifierMessage"] = response.ClaimedIdentifier;
            //If we have a ReturnUrl we MUST be using forms authentication, 
            //so redirect to the original ReturnUrl
            if (Session["ReturnUrl"] != null)
            {
                string url = Session["ReturnUrl"].ToString();
                this.Response.Redirect(url,true);
                return;
            }
            //This should not happen if all controllers have [Authorise] used on them
            else
                throw new InvalidOperationException("There is no ReturnUrl");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Scott Hanselman has a recent [podcast on DoNetOpenAuth](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast229OpenIDAndOpenAuthWithDotNetOpenAuthOpenSourceProgrammerAndrewArnott.aspx). On the podcast, Scott Arnott, author of DotNetOpenAuth, claims that Google's OAuth implementation doesn't properly conform to the specs and says it should fail rather than return null.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Google does not send back any information you request. They will authenticate but that's about it. Hope this helps anyone else with this problem.

Comment: Not true, it is possible to get *some* information back from Google.  See note at foot of http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/help/the-axfetchassregtransform-behavior/

Comment: Not true! Look at the end of this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582048/null-claimsresponse-with-dotnetopenauth-in-asp-net-mvc-2-application